# Or statement in golang templates in combination with gt/lt (greaterThan, lowerThan)

Tags: go, go-html-template

I'm trying out the golang templates but I have one problem which don't know how to fix.

Single statements like below work good.

```golang
  {{ if gt .TotalPrice 0.0 }}
```

But a statement like the one below

```golang
  {{ if or gt .TotalPrice 0.0 gt .TotalMinutes 0.0 }}
```

Results in the following error.

```golang
 executing \"confirmEmail\" at <gt>: wrong number of args for gt: want 2 got 0
```

How does one fix this?

Comment: You need to use parenthesis for grouping. e.g. `or (gt .TotalPrice 0.0) (gt .TotalMinutes 0.0)`

Comment: I just found that out haha sorry for bothering and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found a solution

Based on: https://www.calhoun.io/intro-to-templates-p3-functions/

You can add ( and )

```golang
{{if (ge .Usage .Limit)}}
```

So

```golang
{{ if or (gt .TotalPrice 0.0) (gt .TotalMinutes 0.0) }}
```

Fixed it :)